# mysql DISTINCT() does not work as expected

Tags: mysql, database

I want to get list of posts sorted by number of comments, I've successfully ran following query but it gives repetitive values i.e posts repeat, I want unique of them sorted by number of comments, when I put DISTINCT() around my whole query, an error appears:
 **#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNIQUE(post.pname, post.pid FROM post, COMMENT WHERE post.pid = comment.pid ORD' at line 1**

**Query without DISTINCT()** (Works but of course doesn't give unique values)

```
SELECT post.pname, post.pid
FROM post, 
COMMENT WHERE post.pid = comment.pid
ORDER BY (

SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM COMMENT WHERE comment.pid = post.pid
GROUP BY post.pname
)
```

**Query with DISTINCT()** (doesn't work)

```
SELECT DISTINCT(post.pname, post.pid
FROM post, 
COMMENT WHERE post.pid = comment.pid
ORDER BY (

SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM COMMENT WHERE comment.pid = post.pid
GROUP BY post.pname
))
```

Comment: Do you mean DISTINCT rather than UNIQUE?

Comment: Unique is meant to add constraints whereas distinct is used to select unique rows.

Comment: I'm sorry, DISTINCT too doesn't work

Comment: Did you try to look at ANY tutorial, documentation...? You have a wrong syntax. DISTINCT works as expected, you just have to write your query carefully...

Comment: OH NOES! All these years I've been using DISTINCT and only now I find out that it doesn't work ...

Comment: Read the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html) to get the syntax for DISTINCT .... it's used for the list of columns you want to select, not for the entire query statement; and it isn't a function, so don't bracket it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT distinct(post.pname) FROM post,COMMENT WHERE post.pid = comment.pid ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM COMMENT WHERE comment.pid = post.pid GROUP BY post.pname) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

`DISTINCT` should be used thus:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a,b,c FROM t;
```

without a GROUP BY.  It will find all the (a,b,c) in the table, then de-dup them.

This is broken:

```
SELECT id, a, b FROM t GROUP BY id;
```

That is because it will find all the distinct values of id, but supply random values of `a` and `b` to go with each.

To find out how many of each `foo` there are, this pattern works nicely:

```
SELECT foo, COUNT(*) FROM t GROUP BY foo;
```

Don't use () after `DISTINCT`.

Since I don't understand what you are looking for, I may or may not have provided you enough info to fix your query.  If I have failed, please provide some sample data and the desired output; sometimes reverse engineering is the easiest way to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT post.pname, post.pid
FROM post
    Inner Join ( Select 
                       comment.pid
                     , COUNT(*) As Cant
                 From COMMENT
                 Group By 
                       comment.pid
               ) As x
        On post.pid = x.pid
ORDER BY x.Cant
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT p.*
FROM post p JOIN comment c ON c.postId = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY COUNT(*)
```

Comment: That won't necessarily work "correctly".  Since the GROUP BY does not list all the fields, the code is free to pick random values for things other than p.id.